# Append attributed string to attributed text of UITextField and keep all it's previous colors and attributes

Tags: ios, swift, nsattributedstring

I'm working in Swift with attributed strings. My question is how to append attributed string to attributed text of UITextField and keep all it's previous colors and attributes. When I append new attributed string all previous text in UITextField becomes black and I don't want that, I want to keep it's previous colored parts. This Is the code so far:

```
var newMutableString = NSMutableAttributedString()

if let completionTextHolderText = completionTextHolderText {
    newMutableString = userTextField.attributedText?.mutableCopy() as! NSMutableAttributedString
    let choosenSuggestion = createAttributed(string: completionTextHolderText, with: .blue)
    newMutableString.append(choosenSuggestion)

    let emptySpace = createAttributed(string: " ", with: .black)
    newMutableString.append(emptySpace)
}

userTextField.attributedText = newMutableString.copy() as? NSAttributedString

//-------
    private func createAttributed(string: String, with color: UIColor) -> NSMutableAttributedString {
            let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: string, attributes: [:])
            attributedString.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName,
                                       value: color,
                                       range: NSRange(location: 0, length: string.characters.count))
            return attributedString
    }
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: In simple way it should work. But what attributes userTextField.attributedText has when this code statrts and what createAttributed() method does?

Comment: @AlexShubin - I've edited my question and added `createAttributed()` function. `userTextField.attributedText` could contain some blue or black text. Only attributes are `NSForegroundColorAttributeName`. For instance, black colored word, black colored word, blue colored word, black colored word, blue colored word... etc. Order is not important.

Comment: I got your code working now. I think something happens after your main section and resets attribute color for range. Please post more code for main section

Comment: Also you made things too complicated using this "copy" "mutable" "type casting" etc stuff everywhere with no need for example your createAttributed() probably should return NSAttributedString and may look like this in one line: return NSAttributedString(string: string, attributes: [NSForegroundColorAttributeName : color])

Comment: @AlexShubin - thank you very much. I'll test it more and see what is the problem in my case. This is not refactored code that I've pasted, I've tried more things to make this work. I wouldn't leave it like it is now copied in question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got your code working now. I think something happens before or after your main section and resets attribute color for range.

And heres some idea of how you can refactor it:

```
@IBAction func buttonClick(_ sender: UIButton) {

    if let completionTextHolderText = completionTextHolderText,
        let attrStr = userTextField.attributedText {

        let newMutableString = attrStr.mutableCopy() as! NSMutableAttributedString

        newMutableString.append(
            createAttributed(string: completionTextHolderText+" ", with: .blue)
        )

        userTextField.attributedText = newMutableString
    }
}

private func createAttributed(string: String, with color: UIColor) -> NSAttributedString {
    return NSAttributedString(string: string, attributes: [NSForegroundColorAttributeName : color])
}
```

Comment: Yes, before this code, I'm changing text of UITextField. And that was a problem.